# Load angular textAngular on demand

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set up textAngular on demand i.e. when and if i need it. The textAngular app works if i have the follow html in the file..

```
<body>
<div ng-app="textAngularTest" ng-controller="wysiwygeditor" class="container app">
<div text-angular="text-angular" name="htmlcontent" ng-model="htmlcontent" ta-disabled='disabled'></div> 
</div>
</body>
```

And js function

```
  angular.module("textAngularTest", ['textAngular']).controller('wysiwygeditor', function wysiwygeditor($scope) {
      $scope.orightml = '<h2>Try me!</h2>';
      $scope.htmlcontent = $scope.orightml;
      $scope.disabled = false;
  });
```

To attempt this i am removing the ng-app directive from html and wrapping in a function and use bootstrap to initiate...

```
 function apply(){

      var app= angular.module("textAngularTest", ['textAngular']);

      app.controller('wysiwygeditor', function wysiwygeditor($scope) {
      $scope.orightml = '<h2>Try me!</h2>';
      $scope.htmlcontent = $scope.orightml;
      $scope.disabled = false;
        });

      angular.bootstrap(document, ["textAngularTest"]);
  }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, any suggestions for this?

Codepen
http://codepen.io/ambrosedheffernan/pen/vNEapL

Comment: Which kind of demand? Is it non-angular website, and textAngularTest supposed to be the only Angular app?

Comment: They will be non-angular files, what i want to create a js script that will scan the page and if needed apply the angular tags and bootstrap the app. At the moment its onclick of a button to simulate a later bootstrap. It is the only app at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional bootstrapping may not be the most elegant solution, but in non-SPA case it may work. And yes, it works as it should

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYPqYO

with `ng-app` removed and

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ["textAngularTest"]);
```

added.

Comment: Thanks mate. Do you know offhand if this works if add the controller tags programatically e.g. setAttribute? I think i tried the above but probably with loading of the scripts using js and then adding the tags.

Comment: Adding attributes is ok if done prior to bootstrapping. Otherwise the element with newly added directives (e.g. ng-controller) has to be compiled manually with $compile.